# discord.py (rewrite) How do I create a win condition for a rps(rock, paper, scissors) game?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a win condition for a rock paper scissors game. I've tried to do this but it just gets broken and totally doesn't work. Here's some code to work off of:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os
import random
import asyncio
from asyncio import gather

@client.command()
async def rps(ctx, user_choice):
    rpsGame = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    if user_choice == 'rock' or user_choice == 'paper' or user_choice == 'scissors':
        await ctx.send(f'Choice: `{user_choice}`\nBot Choice: `{random.choice(rpsGame)}`')
        bot_choice = f'{random.choice(rpsGame)}'
    else:
        await ctx.send('**Error** This command only works with rock, paper, or scissors.')

    # Rock Win Conditions #
    if user_choice == 'rock' and bot_choice == 'paper':
        await ctx.send('I won!')
    if user_choice == 'rock' and bot_choice == 'scissors':
        await ctx.send('You won!')
    # Paper Win Conditions #
    if user_choice == 'paper' and bot_choice == 'rock':
        await ctx.send('You won!')
    if user_choice == 'paper' and bot_choice == 'scissors':
        await ctx.send('I won!')
    # Scissor Win Conditions #
    if user_choice == 'scissors' and bot_choice == 'paper':
        await ctx.send('You won!')
    if user_choice == 'scissors' and bot_choice == 'rock':
        await ctx.send('I won!')


client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of your code, I fixed some useless f strings, and moved the indentation of win/lose condition inside the if `user_choice` is in rpsGame to prevent `variable referenced before assignment`

```
@client.command()
async def rps(ctx, user_choice):
    rpsGame = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    if user_choice.lower() in rpsGame: # Better use this, its easier. [lower to prevent the bot from checking a word like this "rOcK or pApeR"
        bot_choice = random.choice(rpsGame)
        await ctx.send(f'Choice: `{user_choice}`\nBot Choice: `{bot_choice}`')
        user_choice = user_choice.lower() # Also prevent a random word such as "rOcK"
        if user_choice == bot_choice:
            await ctx.send('We tied')
        # Rock Win Conditions #
        if user_choice == 'rock' and bot_choice == 'paper':
            await ctx.send('I won!')
        if user_choice == 'rock' and bot_choice == 'scissors':
            await ctx.send('You won!')
        # Paper Win Conditions #
        if user_choice == 'paper' and bot_choice == 'rock':
            await ctx.send('You won!')
        if user_choice == 'paper' and bot_choice == 'scissors':
            await ctx.send('I won!')
        # Scissor Win Conditions #
        if user_choice == 'scissors' and bot_choice == 'paper':
            await ctx.send('You won!')
        if user_choice == 'scissors' and bot_choice == 'rock':
            await ctx.send('I won!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('**Error** This command only works with rock, paper, or scissors.')
```

You should make the bot_choice into a 1 variable, the only things that make it broken because the bot send a different choice than the bot_choice under the `ctx.send` I also added tied option.